# How to get Unity cloud project name with script inside the app?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to get Unity cloud project name/id using script (*Not in editor)?, I manage to get the project name in editor using reflection but what I really need is to get the project name inside the app(*After being published)

```
    Type type = Type.GetType("UnityEditor.Connect.UnityConnect, UnityEditor, Version = 0.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null");
    PropertyInfo instanceInfo = type.GetProperty("instance");
    object settingsInstance = instanceInfo.GetValue(null, null);

    MethodInfo projectName = type.GetMethod("GetProjectName");
    Debug.Log(projectName.Invoke(settingsInstance, new System.Object[] { }));
```

The code above only works for editor.

Comment: `I manage to get the project name in editor using reflection` Please include that code in your question. Also please be clear what specifically isn't working in that code.

Comment: Actually the code is working, but for editor....not sure if it works for non-editor. or maybe another method is required. I will update my question.

Comment: The project name is what you give in PlayerSettings isn't it? So can't you just assign that name in a manager script that you can easily access at runtime? You should give the purpose as it would help.

Comment: @Everts What I am trying to get is the cloud project name, so that I know which analytics the app connected to. I have two id for the project, dev and release.